# Are there substances that could only exist in one state of matter or at least not all of them?

Tags: thermodynamics, material-science, phase-transition, states-of-matter

As an example , water can be found as a liquid, gas or solid. Are there substances that couldn't take all forms of matter? And why?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/242387/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic Actually, [one of the answers](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/242429/154997) is the answer the OP sought.